# How to sync an entire data catalog with RDS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

My goal is to always automatically replicate an S3 bucket with a schema in RDS (MSSQL).

I have a Glue crawler that is triggered by a lambda function on every S3 upload. Hence, the data catalog is always in sync with S3. I am able to create Glue jobs that automatically uploads a specific table from the catalog. 
If a user uploads a new table with new columns, I have to manually create a new job for that table. Is there a way to automate this manual step?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger some logic when a new table is discovered by your crawler, I would suggest you look into creating a [Cloudwatch Event Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html) for a state change in the Glue service.  Specifically, you can invoke a service (i.e. a Lambda function) when the state of a Data Catalog database or table changes.

This lambda function can inspect the state change event and use one of the SDKs to create the job for the new table.